# How do I silently monitor resource usage over time?

Tags: windows-10, resources

Is there a way to monitor resource usage (CPU, memory, GPU, etc.) over an extended period of time on my PC? I would like to monitor which processes are using the most  resources as well.

I have tried perfmon but it redraws the graph every 2 minutes or so, and doesn't show the processes (as far as I can tell).

I am running Windows 10 Education.

Comment: Resource Monitor (Admin Tools) shows processes and you can run for an hour or two (usually enough). It can be minimized but that is about as much as you can do

Answer (score 1):

how about runninng tasklist (it is taskmanager for cmd) from the scheduler and save data to the file as often as you need, and then you could make some charts or other analytics in Excel for example.

To improve this answer: [pslist and perfmon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335242/how-to-display-the-cpu-percentage-usage-by-each-process-in-cmd)

Also the perfmon can be tuned precisely, 4 example:
[image: perfmon tune]
in English: it can use any duration, but (duration/count every n seconds) must be between 2 and 1000. so 2 hours every 10 seconds is available, or 12 hours every minute.

Comment: An edit to show specifically how to do this would make an excellent Answer.

Comment: I don't object to raw data. But how do you get the % CPU usage?